# How to get signed maintenancetool with Qt Installer Framework on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, qt, certificate, installation, signing

The idea is to make Windows 10 stop complaining about unknown publisher for example when trying to uninstall the app. Does it make any sense?

Thanks